# For Loop list missing combinations with Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a list with all possible combinations of numbers that sum up to 34 and there can't be repeated numbers, but I've noticed that some of them don't appear, for example (1, 2, 15, 16) shows up, but not (1, 2, 16, 15)

Is something wrong with my code? Is it a python thing? I'm clueless

```
num = [None] * 4
rng = range(16)
for a in rng:
    num[0] = a+1;

    for b in rng:
        if num.count(b + 1) == 0:
            num[1] = b + 1

            for c in rng:
                if num.count(c + 1) == 0 and 18 < c+1 + num[0] + num[1] < 33:
                    num[2] = c+1
                    for d in rng:
                        if num.count(d+1) == 0 and d+1 + num[0] + num[1] + num[2] == 34:
                            num[3] = d+1
                            print(num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. The first is that your conditional test on `c` should use `<=`, not `<` i.e.

```
18 <= c+1 + num[0] + num[1] <= 33
```

The second is that you are testing the entire `num` array for each value in the range, when you should only test the values up to the current index. This means that once you have written a `d` value of 16 into `num`, it prevents `c` taking that value. You can work around that by slicing `num` before checking for each value e.g.

```
num[0:2].count(c + 1) == 0
```

Your code then becomes:

```
num = [None] * 4
rng = range(16)
for a in rng:
    num[0] = a+1;

    for b in rng:
        if num[0:1].count(b + 1) == 0:
            num[1] = b + 1

            for c in rng:
                if num[0:2].count(c + 1) == 0 and 18 <= c+1 + num[0] + num[1] <= 33:
                    num[2] = c+1
                    for d in rng:
                        if num[0:3].count(d+1) == 0 and d+1 + num[0] + num[1] + num[2] == 34:
                            num[3] = d+1
                            print(num)
```

Note that you can simplify (and speed up) the code significantly by using a set for `num`, and making `rng = range(1, 17)` so you don't have to add 1 all the time:

```
nums2 = []
rng = range(1, 17)
for a in rng:
    for b in rng:
        if not b in { a }:
            for c in rng:
                if not c in { a, b } and 18 <= a + b + c <= 33:
                    d = 34 - a - b - c
                    if not d in { a, b, c }:
                        print([a, b, c, d])
```

Also note that you don't need to loop `d`, just set it to `34 - a - b - c` and check that it isn't in `num`.

Finally, this is a problem that is really better suited to recursion. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear what your algorithm is.  Why is `a` to be between 1 and 17.

Not to write your code for you, but a good general outline would be:

```
For a have any value been 1 and 31: (inclusive)
    For b having any value between 1 and 32 - a (inclusive)
       For c having any value between 1 and 33 - (a + b).  (inclusive)
            d = 34 - (a + b + c)
            output [a, b, c, d]
```

The numbers 31, 32, 33 are the upper limits such that there is a still a possible value for the later digits.

Comment: thanks, I'll try using this approach though I want to keep every number in a range of 1 to 16

Comment: Ah.  That explains the range.  That wasn't in your original description.  Change the "inclusive" upper range to be the min of the value indicated above and 16.